# WPF - DataGrid bind column to method instead of property

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a class that represents a vertex, which can have multiple attributes. Each attribute is identified by its name.

```
public class Vertex
{
    private Dictionary<string, Attr> attributes;

    public Attr GetAttributeByName(string attributeName)
    {
        Attr attribute;
        if (attributes.TryGetValue(attributeName, out attribute))
        {
            return attribute;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to have a `DataGrid` that will have its `ItemsSource` bound to some `ObservableCollection<Vertex>`. Each column should represent one attribute of the vertex. And I want to control the columns at runtime (adding new columns or removing old ones). But I am not able to do that, because new column binding wants the name of property that it will get the cell data from. But I need the binding to call method `GetAttributeByName()` with the name of the attribute to get the data, rather than just getting a property.

```
string newAttributeName = "some_name";
DataGridTextColumn newColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
newColumn.Header = newAttributeName;
newColumn.Binding = ???;

dataGrid.Columns.Add(newColumn);
```

Is there some way to do it?

Comment: You can do something like that with `ObservableCollection<ExpandoObject>` by using a DataTable as the ItemsSource. Either one will require some kind of cleverness to associate it with the attributes. [ExpandoObject does implement INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I'd just go with mm8's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there some way to do it?

No, you can't really bind to methods like this.

But if you expose the `Dictionary<string, Attr>` as a public property of the `Vertex` class, you should be able to bind to this one:

```
string newAttributeName = "some_name";
DataGridTextColumn newColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
newColumn.Header = newAttributeName;
newColumn.Binding = new Binding($"Attributes[{newAttributeName}]");
```